# Best practice for publishing laravel project on Github

Tags: php, git, github, laravel, publish

I am quite new to using Github and want to publish my first project, a Laravel based PHP site, there.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to ensure, that my local DB Config (/app/config/database.php) does not get published?
2. Are there any other things I should pay attention at when publishing my Laravel project?

Thanks for help!
Aaron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel's doc's have a section on how to keep sensitive information out of your config for reasons like publishing on GitHub:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#environment-configuration

Make sure you add the appropriate files to the `.gitignore` file so that they are not committed.

Comment: The link above does not work now. Have things changed with the newer version of Laravel?

Comment: Fixed link, @JHolmes. Config is probably slighty different but extremely similar because it works so well.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, one should add sensitive information to the .gitignore file. You can specify which files will not be published when pushing to a repo. The [official documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) will do a good job explaining how to maintain this file.

If you just want a quick fix, you can open the .gitignore file and add `/app/config/database.php` as a line.

Answer (score 0):

**Database configuration**

You can use server variables to hide your database credentials. Assuming you are using Apache you can put something like this into your `.htaccess` file, or an appropriate `*.conf` file (if you put it in your `.htaccess` file then you should not push it, of course).

```
SetEnv DB_USER username
SetEnv DB_PASS password
```

And then fetch it in your PHP scripts like this:

```
$dbUser = $_SERVER['DB_USER'];
$dbPass = $_SERVER['DB_PASS'];
```

**Other stuff**

Well, aside from various credentials (passwords and stuff like that) you will most likely want to ignore your cache and log folders (if Laravel has those, and they are in the installation directory). I cannot think of much more than that.

Comment: Thanks @sverri-m-olsen! Good idea with Apache server variables.